# Error in invoking target 'client_sharedlib' of makefile oracle 11g centos 7

Tags: oracle11g, centos7

Hi please help me to solve this problem , thank you

I got stuck during installation of **oracle 11g** on **CENTOS 7** and faced this error

> "Error in invoking target 'client_sharedlib' of makefile
>   '/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/rdbms/lib/ins_rdbms.mk'. See
>   '/u01/app/oraInventory/logs/installActions2017-10-17_03-27-55PM.log'
>   for details."

and this is my log file :

```
INFO: /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/bin/genclntsh

INFO: /bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++_nonshared

INFO: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

INFO: genclntsh: Failed to link libclntsh.so.11.1

INFO: make: *** [client_sharedlib] Error 1

INFO: End output from spawned process.
INFO: ----------------------------------
INFO: Exception thrown from action: make
Exception Name: MakefileException
Exception String: Error in invoking target 'client_sharedlib' of makefile '/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/rdbms/lib/ins_rdbms.mk'. See '/u01/app/oraInventory/logs/installActions2017-10-17_03-27-55PM.log' for details.
Exception Severity: 1
```

Comment: `ORACLE_HOME` is set correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
# yum install make
# yum install gcc
```